# Unable to invite user as guest user in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to invite a user as a guest to an Azure Active Directory. When I do it by code or through the portal I get a success response or notification.

However, when I check the list of users, the user is not added as guest to the AAD. When I invite any other users, it works fine.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Azure AD external collaboration settings under "User Settings." This may need to be enabled in your "Properties" as well.

[image]

Also, you need to be logged in as an admin of Azure AD to invite users.

Comment: I see that I didn't add this to my question. It's just one user / email that has this problem. It works fine for 100+ other invitations.

Comment: Does this user have the same permissions as all of the others? Is this user email address formatted in a different way or language?

Comment: No, there's nothing that seems to be different than other users.